# Simultaneously specializing outer and nested class

Tags: c++, templates, inner-classes, template-specialization

The following class template `Sequencer` contains a nested class template `Process`, with two template arguments.

```
template<typename P>
struct Sequencer
{   
    template<typename A , bool = A::CAN_BE_BUFFERED>
    struct Process;
};
```

I would like to specialize `Sequencer` for a custom `struct Foo` while specializing its own version of `Process` to support just one template argument as follows

```
template<>
struct Sequencer<Bar>
{   
    template<typename A>
    struct Process;
};
```

As the implementation is too long, I've posted the entire listing on [ideone](http://ideone.com/S32jxH).

On GCC 4.5.3 I get the following error message

```
prog.cpp:60:24: error: partial specialization ‘Sequencer<Bar>::Process<A>’ does not specialize any template arguments
```

On Visual Studio 2008 I get the following error

```
prog.cpp(62) : error C2753: 'Sequencer<Bar>::Process<A>' : partial specialization cannot match argument list for primary template
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

`Sequencer<Bar>::Process` is a full template, it is not a specialization. It just happens to be a member of a specialization. You shouldn't be declaring it as a specialization:

```
template<typename A>
struct Sequencer<Bar>::Process/*<A>*/
                               //^ remove this
{
};
```

Templates should be thought of as "class generators". `Sequencer<P>` defines a way to make classes from an arbitrary `P`, where `Sequencer<Bar>` gives a particular class to generate when `Sequencer<Bar>` is instantiated. Each generated class is totally separated and unrelated (beyond having been created by the same generator). In this case, this means that the inner class in `Sequencer<Bar>` has no relationship with the inner class in `Sequencer<P>`.